# Multiple Divs with Similar IDs for Toggling

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page that has multiple divs for hide/show. Initially as the page loads, the divs will be hidden, but when the 'Read More' button is clicked, that hidden div will be shown. Now these divs have similar IDs. I was wondering if there is a (shorter) way to write the code, instead of specifying each ID. Can I use the * selector to  apply to all ids that is similar to ('#*-box') format?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready( function () {

function hidesections() {
    $('#bob-box .summary').hide('medium');
    $('#tom-box .summary').hide('medium');
    $('#bill-box .summary').hide('medium');
    $('#mike-box .summary').hide('medium');
};

function reset() {
    $('#bob-read').html('<img src="images/more-arrow.png"> Read More <img src="images/more-arrow.png">');
    $('#tom-read').html('<img src="images/more-arrow.png"> Read More <img src="images/more-arrow.png">');
    $('#bill-read').html('<img src="images/more-arrow.png"> Read More <img src="images/more-arrow.png">');
    $('#mike-read').html('<img src="images/more-arrow.png"> Read More <img src="images/more-arrow.png">');
};



$('#bob-read').toggle(
    function () {
        hidesections();
        $('#bob-box .summary').show('medium');
         reset();
        $('#bob-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
    }, function () {
        if ( $('#bob-box .summary').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            hidesections();
            reset();
        }
        else {
            hidesections();
            reset();
            $('#bob-box .summary').show('medium');
            $('#bob-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
        }
});


$('#tom-read').toggle(
    function () {
        hidesections();
        $('#tom-box .summary').show('medium');
         reset();
        $('#tom-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
    }, function () {
        if ( $('#tom-box .summary').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            hidesections();
            reset();
        }
        else {
            hidesections();
            reset();
            $('#tom-box .summary').show('medium');
            $('#tom-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
        }
});

$('#bill-read').toggle(
    function () {
        hidesections();
        $('#bill-box .summary').show('medium');
         reset();
        $('#bill-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
    }, function () {
        if ( $('#bill-box .summary').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            hidesections();
            reset();
        }
        else {
            hidesections();
            reset();
            $('#bill-box .summary').show('medium');
            $('#bill-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
        }
});



$('#mike-read').toggle(
    function () {
        hidesections();
        $('#mike-box .summary').show('medium');
         reset();
        $('#mike-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
    }, function () {
        if ( $('#mike-box .summary').css('display') == 'block')
        {
            hidesections();
            reset();
        }
        else {
            hidesections();
            reset();
            $('#mike-box .summary').show('medium');
            $('#mike-read').html('<img src="images/less-arrow.png"> Read Less <img src="images/less-arrow.png">');
        }
    });

})
```

```
<section id="bob-box" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
    <img id="image" src="#" align="left" style="padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:10px">
    <h2>Title Here</h2>
    <article id="short">
        This party will be shown.
    </article>

    <div class="summary">
        This part will initially be hidden.
    </div>

    <a id="bob-read" class="read" href="javascript:;">
        <img src="#">
        Read More
        <img src="#">
    </a>
</section>
```

Comment: why can't you just use a class?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm controlling the height of the divs since they all are different heights, so I figured that IDs was the best way to go.

Comment: Likely in css (no height code shown) but that doesn't mean you can't have an ID and any number of classes on an element. It's not uncommon to use classes for different purposes ( scripting vs css) for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use wildcards in your selector, something like `*[id*='-box']`

```
$("*[id*='-box']").find(".summary").hide('medium');
```

this would match all the elements with the attribute id containing the word `-box`, and the trailing part should be clear

Answer (score 1):

Use a common class name for all the elements you want to show or hide.

That way, you will just need one line of code

```
$('.YOUR_CLASS').hide('medium');
```